# Symfony and Twig - JMS i18n is only extracting from tags but not filter

Tags: php, symfony, internationalization, twig, twig-extension

In a Symfony web app, I have the JMS i18n stuff for translation installed.

If I use it like

```
{% trans %}layout.name.default{% endtrans %}
```

And run the extract script it works like a charm. Exactly as I want it to.

Unfortunately I need to pass a localized string at some point to a function (a macro in TWIG) and there it doesn't work anymore.

```
{{ _self.menuItem('layout.navigation.home'|trans(), path('foo_homepage')) }}
```

When I run the export with

```
php app/console translation:extract de --config=app --output-format=xliff
php app/console translation:extract en --config=app --output-format=xliff
php app/console translation:extract fr --config=app --output-format=xliff
php app/console translation:extract it --config=app --output-format=xliff
```

It just ignores my `layout.name.home`. How can I make it clear to JMS to read that too?

Answer (score 1):

So it seams that it was just some cached version, it tried to read from. After deleting the cache manually with `rm app/cache/* -rf` and rebuild the translation files every thing seams to work.